# Elegant way to achieve this with a generic type in key

Tags: typescript, object, types

I made a code to filter any field of my object no matter the type received by making a generic type, but I didn't find an elegant way to do it in typescript, is there another way to do it?

```
type Test = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  actived: boolean;
}

const dd: Array<Test> = [
  {id: 2, name: "sss", actived: true},
  {id: 3, name: "tt", actived: false},
  {id: 4, name: "mmmmm", actived: true},
  {id: 5, name: "tttt", actived: true}
]
const run = <T, K extends keyof T>(datas: Array<T>, key: K) => {
  return datas.filter(data => castTForFilter(data[key]))
}

const castTForFilter = <K,v = null>(key: K): boolean => {
  switch(typeof key) {
    case "string":
      return key.includes("tt")
    case "number":
      return key == 2
    case "boolean":
      return key == true
    default:
      return false
  }
}

console.log(run(dd, "name"))
console.log(run(dd, "id"))
console.log(run(dd, "actived"))
```

Comment: Can you please explain better what you're trying to do? The code is a little confusing. is `run` missing an argument for filter value? also, in `castTForFilter` `key` actually receives the value, not the key (`data[key]` is the value).

Comment: You can curry `castTForFilter`, see the example tsplay.dev/m3z9LN . Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it is a value, the code can filter on an object key
instead of doing data.name or data.id I made a code where you just pass it the object array and the key as parameter then after if the key is a string I can use the string functions to compare and if it's a number the number functions, so I typeof in a switch case the key and I wanted an elegant way to do it

example:
string key: we can include,chartAt etc...
key of type number : we can toString etc..

Comment: please provide expected result of better way into the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@captain-yossarian your code is more or less elegant than mine but I was expecting to solve this more with types than typecript offers, but that's OK.

your code :

```
type Test = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    actived: boolean;
}
const customData: Test[] = [
    { id: 2, name: "sss", actived: true },
    { id: 3, name: "tt", actived: false },
    { id: 4, name: "mmmmm", actived: true },
    { id: 5, name: "tttt", actived: true }
]

const run = <
    Elem extends Test,
    Data extends Elem[],
    >(data: [...Data], cb: (elem: Elem) => boolean) => data.filter(cb)



const castTForFilter = <Key extends keyof Test>(key: Key) =>
    <Elem extends Test>(elem: Elem) => {
        const value = elem[key]
        switch (typeof value) {
            case "string":
                return value.includes("tt")
            case "number":
                return value == 2
            case "boolean":
                return value == true
            default:
                return false
        }
    }


const result = run(customData, castTForFilter('id'))
console.log(result)
```